# Bootstrap pop-up modal-backdrop doesn't disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a slight problem when pop-up is closing; modal-backdrop is not closing.

This code blog for opening pop-up:

```
<script>
    $('div.ProjePartialGovde').click(function (el) {
        var projeid = $(this).data('id');
        $('.popupListe').html('içerik hazırlanıyor...');
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: '@Url.Action("ProjeOzetPartial", "Home")',
            data: { projeID: projeid,ilID:@ViewBag.ilID }
        })
            .done(function (msg) {
                $('.popupListe').html(msg);
                $("#detayModal").modal();
            });
    });
```

And this is my pop-up page:

I'm having trouble with my back button. When I clicked back button it goes backwards but there is something gray on the screen which is: "modal-backdrop in"

```
<div class="modal" id="detayModal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control">Başlangıç / Bitiş Tarihleri: @Model.SozBasTarihi / @Model.SozBitisTarihi</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control">Nakdi ve Fiziki Tamamlanma Oranları: %@Model.NakdiTamOrani / %@Model.FizikiTamOrani</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                
                <!-- I HAVE PROBLEM HERE -->
                <button class="ProjeListesiGeri" data-dissmiss="modal" data-backdrop="false">BACK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- GO BACK CODE -->
<script>
    $('.ProjeListesiGeri').click(function (el) {
        $('.popupListe').html('içerik hazırlanıyor...');
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: '@Url.Action("ProjelerListesiPartial", "Home")',
            data: { ilID: @ViewBag.ilID }
        })
            .done(function (msg) {
                $('.popupListe').html(msg);
            });
    });
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. I added in my back code this line: `$("#detayModal").modal('hide');` and it is working.

So full code:

```
<script>
    $('.ProjeListesiGeri').click(function (el) {
        $("#detayModal").modal('hide'); <!-- I added this line. -->
        $('.popupListe').html('içerik hazırlanıyor...');
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: '@Url.Action("ProjelerListesiPartial", "Home")',
            data: { ilID: @ViewBag.ilID }
        })
            .done(function (msg) {
                $('.popupListe').html(msg);
            });
    });
</script>
```